# git file rename using filter smudge / clean

Tags: git, filter

What I'd like is a method to *smudge* rename a file and *clean* rename it back, in git.

(I'd also like this to to work on Windows--Cygwin fine/preferred--and *nix.)

Here's what I'd like to have happen:

```
chipA1.py:
  # Version "@(#)0_14_5"
  # ... more python code here ...

chipB9.py:
  # Version "@(#)0_3_2"
  # ...
```

I want git to store these files in the repo as chipA1.py and chipB9.py so all edits to them are simply tracked as usual by git, but upon a `git pull` or `git clone` have them appear on my (Windows Cygwin or Mac OS X) local filesystem as:

```
chipA1_0_14_5.py
chipB9_0_3_2.py
```

After editing the chipA1_0_14_5.py file in our toolset's IDE, I'd like the *clean* filter to automagically rename it back to chipA1.py, i.e. strip any underscore+digits after the first underscore.

Can this be done, using git smudge / clean?

I only need to do this for a small handful of files, all which should be in the same repo because they're related and work with one another via RPC mechanisms. So I'd separately add to our `.gitattributes` file the exact half-dozen or so filenames that need the smudging and cleaning filter applied.

*Rationale: I need to do this because our poorly featured embedded toolkit makes it essentially impossible to see the code contents of a target running on a chipset, so we need to be able to identify which version of chipA1.py or chipB9.py is running, by viewing the version # right on the filename itself in this toolkit's IDE.*

Here is what I have, but which does *not* work (happens to be written in ruby, but I'm open to bash shell scripts that will work in both OS X & Cygwin on Windows):

./add_ver:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
data = STDIN.read

filename = ARGV.first

ver = data[/@\(#\)([\d_]*$)/]
ver = $1

dot = filename.rindex('.') if filename
filename_with_ver = filename[0...dot] + '_' + ver + filename[dot...filename.length]

puts data.
        gsub('$Version$', '$Version: ' + ver + ' $').
        gsub('$Filename$', '$Filename: ' + filename + ' should be transformed into: ' + filename_with_ver + ' $')
STDIN.close

exit system("git mv -v -f #{filename} #{filename_with_ver}")
```

./remove_ver:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
data = STDIN.read

filename_with_ver = ARGV.first

ver = data[/@\(#\)([\d_]*$)/]
ver = $1

dot = filename_with_ver.rindex('.')
filename_without_ver = filename_with_ver[0...dot].split('_').first + filename_with_ver[dot...filename_with_ver.length]

puts data.
        gsub(/$Version.*$/, '$Version$').
        gsub(/$Filename.*$/, '$Filename$')
STDIN.close

exit system("git mv -v -f #{filename_with_ver} #{filename_without_ver}")
```

Note that I've tried both `git mv -v -f` as well as `mv` alone (without git), and neither accomplish what I want.

The relevant parts of my `config -l` are:

```
filter.filenamevers.smudge=./add_ver %f
filter.filenamevers.clean=./remove_ver %f
```

And of my `.gitattributes` (I'm just using test.txt as a test file for now, it'll be foo.py later):

```
*.txt filter=filenamevers
```

And finally, here is my test file:
test.txt:

```
# Current Release: @(#)1_0_1

# $Version$
# $Filename$
```

Of course the $Version$ and $Filename$ fields are just 'test' fields, I really only need/want the first line, which is how I'll modify what name the checked-out filename gets transformed into.

It seems to run fine when run without using the usual git `rm test.txt ; git checkout -- test.txt` method to run it through git's filters:

```
$ ./add_ver < test.txt test.txt
# Current Release: @(#)1_0_1

# $Version: 1_0_1 $
# $Filename: test.txt should be transformed into: test_1_0_1.txt $
Renaming test.txt to test_1_0_1.txt
```

Obviously, I'm in a bit of a chicken & egg situation because git is tracking `test.txt` and I'm trying to `mv` it. Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be a post-checkout to do the renames, a simple tracked file to list which ones, and tell my editor to read that list and automatically save both copies when writing to a file on the list.  In vim it'd be a [bufwritepost autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html), any programmer's editor should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @jthill I've already implemented something similar using two repos--which I was hoping to avoid by using smudge/clean--that is, I was hoping to not have to have all the generated files saved into the repo, so they could (using clean/smudge) be passed back & forth by different devs by simply changing the version #s inside the files themselves (which get translated into versions embedded into the filenames by the smudging). What I've done instead to solve this for now is have two repos, a 'working' repo and the 'production' repo and use scripts to shuttle between the repos.

Comment: maybe add a commit alias, frontend it to do clean/commit/smudge, likewise with the others, merge/rebase/etc.